# error mismatching in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, singlestore

I am trying to return `RDD[(String,String,String)]` and I am not able to do that using `flatMap`. I tried `(tweetId, tweetBody, gender)` and `(tweetId, tweetBody, gender)` but it give me an error of type mismatch can you guid me to know how I can return `RDD[(String, String, String)]` from `flatMap`

```
override def transform(sqlContext: SQLContext, rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]], config: UserTransformConfig, logger: PhaseLogger): DataFrame = {
    val idColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("id")
    val bodyColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("body")
    val genderColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("gender")

    // convert each input element to a JsonValue
    val jsonRDD = rdd.map(r => byteUtils.bytesToUTF8String(r))

    val hashtagsRDD: RDD[(String,String, String)] = jsonRDD.mapPartitions(r => {
      // register jackson mapper (this needs to be instantiated per partition
      // since it is not serializable)
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

      r.flatMap(tweet => tweet match {
        case _ :: tweet =>
        val rootNode = mapper.readTree(tweet)
        val tweetId = rootNode.path("id").asText.split(":")(2)
        val tweetBody = rootNode.path("body").asText
        val tweetVector =  new HashingTF().transform(tweetBody.split(" "))
        val result =genderModel.predict(tweetVector)
        val gender = if(result == 1.0){"Male"}else{"Female"}

        (tweetId, tweetBody, gender)
       // Array(1).map(x => (tweetId, tweetBody, gender))

      })

    })

    val rowRDD: RDD[Row] = hashtagsRDD.map(x => Row(x._1,x._2,x._3))
    val schema = StructType(Array(StructField(idColumnName,StringType, true),StructField(bodyColumnName, StringType, true),StructField(genderColumnName,StringType, true)))
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
  }
}
```

Comment: please describe your problem little bit more

Comment: I am trying to return with RDD[String,String,String] and I am not able to do that using flat map. I tried 
(tweetId, tweetBody, gender) and 
{tweetId, tweetBody, gender}
but it give me and error of type mismatch

can you guid me to know how I can return RDD[(String, String, String)]  from flatmap

Comment: Please add corresponding information to your question, supply error texts and fix formatting

Comment: editted, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `map` instead of `flatMap`.
`flatMap` is being used when result type of parameter function is collection or `RDD`

I.e. `flatMap` is being used when every element of current collection is mapped to zero or more elements.
While `map` is being used when every element of current collection is mapped to exactly one element.

`map`  with `A => B` exchanges symbol `A` with symbol `B` in [functorial types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), i.e. transforms `RDD[A]` to `RDD[B]`

`flatMap` could be read as *`map` then `flatten`* in [monadic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). E.g. you have and `RDD[A]` and parameter function is of type `A => RDD[B]` result of simple `map` will be  `RDD[RDD[B]]` and that pair of occurences could be simplified to just `RDD[B]` via `flatten`

Here the example of succesfully compiled code.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}

class UserTransformConfig {
  def getConfigString(name: String): Option[String] = ???
}

class PhaseLogger
object byteUtils {
  def bytesToUTF8String(r: Array[Byte]): String = ???
}

class HashingTF {
  def transform(strs: Array[String]): Array[Double] = ???
}

object genderModel {
  def predict(v: Array[Double]): Double = ???
}

def transform(sqlContext: SQLContext, rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]], config: UserTransformConfig, logger: PhaseLogger): DataFrame = {
  val idColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("id")
  val bodyColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("body")
  val genderColumnName = config.getConfigString("column_name").getOrElse("gender")

  // convert each input element to a JsonValue
  val jsonRDD = rdd.map(r => byteUtils.bytesToUTF8String(r))

  val hashtagsRDD: RDD[(String, String, String)] = jsonRDD.mapPartitions(r => {
    // register jackson mapper (this needs to be instantiated per partition
    // since it is not serializable)
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    r.map { tweet =>
      val rootNode = mapper.readTree(tweet)
      val tweetId = rootNode.path("id").asText.split(":")(2)
      val tweetBody = rootNode.path("body").asText
      val tweetVector = new HashingTF().transform(tweetBody.split(" "))
      val result = genderModel.predict(tweetVector)
      val gender = if (result == 1.0) {"Male"} else {"Female"}

      (tweetId, tweetBody, gender)

    }
  })

  val rowRDD: RDD[Row] = hashtagsRDD.map(x => Row(x._1, x._2, x._3))
  val schema = StructType(Array(StructField(idColumnName, StringType, true), StructField(bodyColumnName, StringType, true), StructField(genderColumnName, StringType, true)))
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
}
```

please note how much I should bring from my imagination because you did not supply the [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general questions like this are not worth to answer

Comment: but the result of above code is RDD[(string,string,strin)]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to answer my question. But what i need us

Comment: Flatmap( tweet=> (tweetvody,tweetid,gender)) so how can that done